# Создание появляющегося сайдбара при помощи JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть макет сайта. [image: макет сайта]

Нужно, чтобы при на нажатии на иконку сверху слева появлялся сайдбар слева под названием (или же просто `display: block`), и соответственно при повторном нажатии на вышеупомянутую иконку сайдбар прятался.

Информацию искал, но корявый код, написанный мною, не хочет работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изобретайте велосипед, возьмите какой-нибудь [sidebar plugin для jQuery](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-sliding-sidebar-panel-plugins/) и радуйтесь жизни.

Можно и в [sidebar на чистом CSS3](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/umEgv) вообще без JavaScript. transition полезная штуковина.

Для отключения картинок, как просил ТС:

```
$( "#sidebar" ).click(function() {
    $( ".sideposts" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Еще что-нибудь.
    });
});
```

Comment: Тоже думал над Jquery, но хотел попробывать реализовать на чистом js)
А за ссылку спасибо)

Comment: Есть еще вариант с одним css, вообще без JS

Comment: Тоже неплохой вариант, спасибо)

Comment: К продолжению вопроса, хотел бы что б количество постов уменьшалось ровно на 1( розмер сайдбара и поста с margin-ом ровны) 
то есть при нажатии на иконку випадение сайдбара и уменшение контейнера для постов, реально такое с css?
Мой небольшой опыт подсказивает что нет.

Comment: Да, придется дописать немного js, если действительно нужно уменьшать их количество при появлении панели.

Comment: Не могли бы вы вкратце  описать данные две(я так думаю) функции, то  есть клик, внутри которой функция замены css. (в общем виде)

Comment: Благодарен, пойду переписывать свой код)

Comment: Не за что, удачи!